# Algorithm to make items background color for a table with two column like chess table

Tags: algorithm

I want to create an Algorithm to Create some thing like in the picture where the background color of items be like a chess table (just Algorithm Plz), because i have recycleviews in android and i want to make it like that ..

thanks for helping

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The square at row `r`, column `c` is "white" if and only if `r + c` is even.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but can you explain some more

Answer (score 0):

I can write the pseudocode for you

```
int boxes[10][10];
for (int i =0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        if (i+j % 2 ==0)
            Color color = "red";
        else
            Color color = "green";
        int width = Getwidth(i);   // get the width of you want, since all boxes have same width at the same column. 
        int hight = Getheight(j);  //Same as before
        drawBox(i,j,width,hight, color);
    }
}
```